# Is it ok to do an insert from inserted using a variable replacement value in place of a column from inserted?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Hi I am just wondering!

Is it ok to do the following;

```
INSERT INTO myTable(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)

SELECT field1, field2, *@MyVariable*, field4, *@MyOtherVariable* FROM inserted
```

Just to my junior experience, asking for a field from inserted of which I have replaced with my value does not seem right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a valid SQL statement there.

You are able to use variables and literals in a SELECT when INSERTing. You're basically saying: "take each row from `inserted`, and use a single value respectively for field3 and field5 in these two variables to apply to all rows".

It sounds as if you're asking whether it's 'right'. That'd be up to your business logic or schema. Perhaps your source tables doesn't have a column3 and column5. Perhaps they do exist, but they're not wanted/relevant to your `myTable`.

Suggest posting the definition of your trigger.

Comment: Ok Thanks, have a +1 on me :-)  It would be marked as answer already if time limit was removed ha!

Comment: @dotnetnewb post your trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about why you might want to do that in a trigger. Suppose you have an audit trigger and you want to add the date the operation happened, setting the date to the current date first and then making sure all the records in inserted use that date when being added to the audit table is the right way to do it if the date is not a field in your initial table. In a trigger variables are often used to grab some sort of system information that is not stored in the base table or to set the value of some variable based on a calculation. It should only be done if you want all the records in the inserted table to have the same value.

On the other hand if you are setting the variable in a way that indicates you think there will only be one record, then the trigger is wrong and needs to be fixed. Usually these type of mistakes end up with the insert to the other table taking place in a values clause not a select.

The key to understanding if it is the correct thing to do is to look at what would happen if there were multiple records in the inserted table.

Let me give you an example:

```
declare @client_id int
declare @date datetime
select @client_id = client_id from inserted
set @date = getdate()

insert table2 (client_id, action_date)
values (@client_id, @date)
```

In this case setting the value of the variable for client_id is wrong as there could be 1000 records in the inserted table and 20 different client_ids. However, setting the date field would be a good use of a variable as you would want the action date to be the same for the whole batch.